# how to understand the context of any sentence

Tags: java

i m creating a mobile application that will require understanding  the context of the sms. please give some idea. how can i implement it??

by understanding the context of the sms i mean that i want a program that can understand the meaning of the message typed by the user....

Comment: In other words, do you need a [natural language understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_understanding) system that transforms each message into a representation of its meaning?

Answer (score 2):

There is a long history of NLP (and AI) that is suggested by your question. However, clearly, you are not going to get a PhD to undertake this project. I strongly recommend that you think carefully about *precisely* what you want to learn from each message. Named Entity extraction, as available open source at [gate](http://gate.ac.uk) might give you a leg up.